# How to display an AlertDialog on top of a system application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app you click a button that launches the gallery and after you select a photo from the gallery my app compresses the photo and generates a thumbnail. This action takes a few seconds and I want to display a dialog that says something to the user to let them know my app is doing something. The problem is while the photo is being generated the gallery is still active on the screen and my dialog doesn't show up. Currently with the below code I am getting an error about "permission denied for this window type" and "badtoken". I do have a permission set in my manifest for "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

My Question is basically how can I make this dialog show on top of the gallery view?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {

        // Do this if result came from selection in android photo gallery
        case PICK_EXISTING_PHOTO_RESULT_CODE: {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("").setMessage("Optimizing Photo...")
                        .setCancelable(false).create();
                alertDialog.getWindow().setType(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG);
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Have you considered [Status Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: @0gravity Yes but I feel like a dialog is more appropriate for my case.

Comment: If this is running in onActivityResult(), doesn't that mean that the gallery app has already closed?  ...assuming the gallery app was called through an Intent called with startActivityForResult()

Comment: @VoteBrian Well when you run my app during the time the image is being processed it stops on the gallery screen and doesn't return to my app until after it's finished.

Comment: I think you can use AsyncTask in which you can easily show a progressDialog

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think you'll be able to show a Dialog from the gallery app.  You should be passing off to the gallery app only for the file selection, then handling the processing in your app, correct?  So it wouldn't be in the gallery app that you inform the user that the image is being processed.
- I think you'll want to add a ProgressBar, not an AlertDialog.  Dialogs are usually used when the user has some options, or when you want to confirm something, not just to indicate a process is running.

I feel like your timeline should be:

1. Your Activity

   - User presses button indicating intent to select image
2. Gallery App

   - User selects image
   - Gallery App returns file/filename
3. Your Activity

   - Begin showing ProgressBar
   - Process image
   - End ProgressBar

Comment: Basically that is what i'm trying to do, just not with a progressbar. The code above is the the code that is run when my app is notified that a photo has been selected from the gallery.... but when it runs this code it pauses on the gallery app..... which i don't want, but it does and I don't know a way around it.